# Setting up a scene for image capturing and image processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm building a box where the user will put their foot and then have measurements of their feet taken.

My 1st tier goal is to take basic measurements and my reach goal is to build a 3d model of the person's foot.

Here are what some images from my first attempts and prototyping.

[back of the foot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxR0o.png) | [inside of the foot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ58Q.png) | [outside of the foot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg0RX.png) | [top of the foot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv0A9.png)

So, my big advantage is that I have a lot of control over the scene.

I want to use this fact to set things up so I can get reliable measurements using pictures.

So my questions are as follows: 
1) What is the best way to set the scene up? Right now I'm going to have a blue background, lights, and a contrasting sock to create a consistent internal image. Is there a more 'optimal' contrast to use? As you can see below, it's working decently.

2) What's an easy way for me to get reliable pixel to mm measurements? I can use a patterned sock (to increase feature density) and then two cameras from each viewpoint, but it would be great to minimize the number of cameras I need.

I'm going to leave the questions there as not to overload this post - but if people have any other tips it would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to 1) would essentially be a "green screen" or "blue screen".

The idea is to carefully illuminate the background so that there are no shadows. Then, you can apply a color threshold, and everything that is not that specific color is the foreground. So far in your images, there is a quite a bit of shadow, which may be able to be eliminated by careful lighting. You'll have to experiment with how much of that is an issue for you.

2) This a little tougher, but possible. You will need to know the position and direction of your cameras, the lens parameters (such as F/#), the sensor parameters (pixel pitch/spacing). With this information, you should be able to locate the extrema of the foot and get some measurements. Here's a general diagram of how this might work. You could use the top view to locate the mid-line of the foot so you know how far it is from the side cameras. Then, you have all the information you need to solve of pixel to real-space measurements. The top camera is easy; since everything is in a plane (assuming the camera is properly aligned and rectified) all you have to do is put a ruler on the floor and take some pictures of it. Then, you can measure the pixels to real-space conversion directly from the image.

[image]

For your 3-d modeling issue, I'd like to point out that you don't actually have to get a full point cloud. You could just get a model of a foot and scale it for display based on the measurements you make. In any case, good luck on your project!

Comment: I was thinking about printing an Aruco pattern on the inside blue walls of the box. I would then use this known pixel/mm ratio to do the resolution.

Comment: I don't think that will work as well as you hope for a side view. I can edit my answer to illustrate this, but the problem is that there is an ambiguity between size and distance for objects viewed through a camera. If you use some method to determine distance, you can determine size. But in your case, the marker would be at a different distance than the foot, which means there would be some error in your approximation.

Comment: I was thinking the aruco in place of the ruler for the top view. Yeah, that side view is really the problem though. So is multiple cameras with overlapping field of views so I can implement stereo the best way to do this? I was also thinking about using a kinect, but I think it would make things much more difficult.

Comment: Sure, that might work. I might not have communicated it clearly, but my point was that you may be able to use the top camera to locate the foot in a 2-d plane; then use that location information to constrain the side view measurement problem. I wouldn't immediately jump to multiple cameras or a kinect; with careful geometry you can get good measurements without that added complexity.

Comment: Got it. I think that's a good approach. I'm going to take some time to think about how I can constrain the side views and make it work. Thanks for the answer and comments.